# Dealing with 3.5 and 4 inch screen, is there a way to see what the screen size is?

Tags: ios

I'm writing my first iphone app after iphone 5 came ut.  I see apple now has 2 screen sizes to deal with.
Is there a way to see what screen size your app is running on? I was thinking about having a seperate vue class for inch screen size and then a base class so thet can share the functionality.  Seems kind of complicated, is there a more simple way to handle this???

Comment: There are countless existing discussions about supporting both iPhone screen sizes. Please start by looking at any number of them.

Comment: You should use AutoLayout for handling positions of objects in the view. Also the Image Assets can help with picking right images depending on the screen size.

Comment: i'd suggest looking into `Autolayout` / `AutoSizing` functionality. no need to create separate views